# Access a struct variable inside a class

Tags: swift, class, struct

I have a struct variable that is wrapped into an `NSObject` class.

Here is how it looks:

```
class myClass: NSObject{

struct myStruct {
    var array1: [String]
    var additionalInfo: String?
    var array2: [String]
}

var myVar = [myStruct(array: ["value1"], additionalInfo:nil, array2: ["value1","value2"])]
}
```

My goal is to append the `myVar` variable with values from a different class and to access them.

I'm trying this code for appending:

```
var classAccess = myClass()
classAccess.myVar.append(array1:["value 3"], additionalInfo:nil, answers:["value 3"])
```

However, I get all sorts of nasty errors when I try to compile.

How do you access it the proper way?

Comment: Why do you have the struct inside of a class?

Comment: @PeterFoti i want to access it from both MainController and AppDelegate directly instead of creating a new instance for each one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that, but you have to use the `MyStruct` initializer and you have to reference the struct from outside the class with `MyClass.MyStruct`

```
class MyClass: NSObject{

  struct MyStruct {
    var array1: [String]
    var additionalInfo: String?
    var array2: [String]
  }

  var myVar = [MyStruct(array1: ["value1"], additionalInfo:nil, array2: ["value1","value2"])]
}


var classAccess = MyClass()
classAccess.myVar.append(MyClass.MyStruct(array1:["value 3"], additionalInfo:nil, array2:["value 3"]))
```

Note: for better readability I capitalized the struct and class names